# Parse String 0405066 to "time"/"datetime" datatype: 04:05:066

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm working with a filename that contains an unformatted date as a string of 7 numbers:

```
0405066
```

How can I turn the above into:

```
04:04:066
```

I have tried many `CONVERT(time, '0405066',code)`'s but none of them have been effective.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the units on each element of your time code?  Only minutes, seconds, milliseconds?  no hour?

Answer (score 0):

This will get the string you wanted:

```
LEFT(@time, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time,3,2) + ':' + right(@time,3)
```

But that will not convert to a valid time format either.  You must specify all parts hours, minutes, and seconds when including the milliseconds.  If the hours are just missing then this will convert to the time datatype:

```
convert(time,'00:' + LEFT(@time, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@time,3,2) + ':' + right(@time,3))
```